# How to set Ctrl + Enter as hotkey in Mozilla SDK?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How to set `Ctrl` + `Enter` as hotkey in Mozilla SDK ?

There is no documentation on how to assign the enter key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accel-return` should work:

```
require("sdk/hotkeys").Hotkey({
    combo: "accel-return",
    onPress: function() {
        console.log('control+enter pressed');
    }
});
```